# MonoDevelop Install: Certificate Failure

Tags: nuget, certificate, monodevelop

While trying to install MonoDevelop 5.12.0.266 after successfully running `/.configure` I stumbled upon an error while trying to run `make`. I am running parrot 4.14.0-parrot13-amd64. This is the TraceBack:

```
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces.2.8.0-beta3-62728-05.
    WARNING: Unable to find version '2.2.0' of package 'Humanizer.Core'.
      https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
      An error occurred while sending the request
      Error: TrustFailure (A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.)
      A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
      Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
        at /home/c4ffrey/Downloads/mono-5.12.0.226/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
      https://dotnet.myget.org/F/roslyn/api/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://dotnet.myget.org/F/roslyn/api/
    v3/index.json.
      An error occurred while sending the request
      Error: TrustFailure (A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.)
      A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
      Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
...
    at /home/c4ffrey/Downloads/mono-5.12.0.226/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
  https://www.myget.org/F/azure-appservice/api/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://www.myget.org/F/azure-appservice/api/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request
  Error: TrustFailure (A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.)
  A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
  Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
    at /home/c4ffrey/Downloads/mono-5.12.0.226/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request
  Error: TrustFailure (A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.)
  A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
  Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
    at /home/c4ffrey/Downloads/mono-5.12.0.226/external/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.c:1132
```

I came up with a solution so this is mostly for users who come to the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to the Problem above is to run `sudo cert-sync /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` as it adds the required certificates to your system.